# `.vimrc` unsuccessful in setting highlight style

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, highlight, spell-checking

1) To underline misspelled words, I can execute the following in an open buffer:

```
:hi clear SpellBad
:hi SpellBad cterm=underline
:set spell
```

2) However, if I write in my `.vimrc` the first two lines, namely:

```
:hi clear SpellBad
:hi SpellBad cterm=underline
```

and when I open a file, I execute `:set spell`, misspelled words are highlighted in color, but not underlined.

Why are the `.vimrc` settings in 2) overridden? How can I get the same result as in 1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are likely overridden by your colorscheme of choice (even if it is default).

My suggested fix is

```
augroup colors
  au!
  au ColorScheme * hi whatever
augroup
```

Answer (score 1):

D. Ben"s answer is correct one but a bit terse.

I also answered a similar question with detailed solution at [How to set a colorscheme that still shows spelling errors?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18295/how-to-set-a-colorscheme-that-still-shows-spelling-errors/)

`au` is very useful!