# undercurl not visible to me in gvim on WIndows 10

Tags: syntax-highlighting, gvim, microsoft-windows, spell-checking

I like to use `undercurl` to highlight spelling mistakes in Vim.  I believe it does this by default.  This works fine in MacOS and Linux but it isn't visible for `gvim` on Windows 10.  Originally, I thought it was missing but it turns out that it's there very faintly.

[image: undercurl on Windows]

I apologize for the bad font but this is what I get when I use `-u NONE`.  It also doesn't work with my customized font, `Consolas:h10` or `guifont=DejaVu_Sans_Mono_for_Powerline:h10:cANSI:qDRAFT`.

Compare this to the same settings on Mac.  The `undercurl` is more visible.

[image: undercurl on Mac]

Is there a way to get `undercurl` to display more boldly on Windows 10?  I am using `gvim` 8.2.  I found [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/25368/2399) but it's not relevant since I still have the the problem with a minimal configuration (i.e. no `vim-solarized` `colorscheme`.  Maybe another font is better?  Some accessibility setting?

Comment: Isn't there a tiny undercurl below the `xxx` in your screenshot?

Comment: Hmmm, my old eyes can't see that.  I guess I should change this question to "How do I make undercurl visible.

Comment: I agree, it's very hard to see. Does changing the font size (and of course the font, the default is not very nice) make a difference? How about turning on directx rendering (see `:h 'renderoptions' `)?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, thanks for the question.  Changing the font or the font size seems to have no effect on the visibility of `undercurl`.  Similarly for `renderoptions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe another font is better? Some accessibility setting?

GVim has different undercurl implementation in Windows and Mac. The code for Mac uses "LineTo" primitive, but Windows-specific procedure sticks to "SetPixel" and you can't do anything about this except choosing more contrast color or opening issue on Vim's github.

I'd rather choose not to have "undercurl" at all. For example, make SpellBad look as Underlined instead:

```
augroup color_fix | au!
    autocmd ColorScheme * hi! link SpellBad Underlined
augroup end
```